# Export to Excel with grouping and style

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, c#-4.0

I have to export data to excel. In Excel sheet i have to keep some styling and grouping functionality. i have tried a POC with EPPlus.dll but getting an error

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried it in my vs 2010 frame work 4.

can any body tell me about how can i achieve this. or about the error or any other dlls with download url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what your code is for export or what you are exporting but here are some good tips- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589768/exporting-data-to-excel-in-vb-net.

Comment: Did you reference the DLL? At best, use nuget to obtain EPPLUs.